# Vue nested custom components scope

Tags: vue.js

I would like to create a set of reusable utility/non-ui components that will empower any HTML table by allowing it to be:

- attached to a http data-source
- sorted
- paginated
- filtered, etc

The code that I wish I had when consuming it is as follows:

```
<my-app>
  <data-table :url="url">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <dt-th sort-key="name">Name</dt-th>
          <dt-th sort-key="surname">Surname</dt-th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="row in data">
          <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.surname }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </data-table>
</my-app>
```

The biggest issue with the code above is that Vue looks in `MyApp` component in order to resolve `dt-th` element, `data` expression, etc. Is there a way to make this work?

You can find my pseudo-app here: https://plnkr.co/edit/30Z7L3zrfrGmED17QrIh?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data issue can be solved using a [scoped slot](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Scoped-Slots).

```
const DataTable = {
  components: {
    'dt-th': DataTableHeaderCell
  },
  props: ['src'],
  data () {
    return {
      data: [
        { name: 'Gale', surname: 'Marlon' },
        { name: 'Corwin', surname: 'Hayden' }
      ]
    }
  },
  created () {
    EventBus.$on('sort', this.sort)
  },
  methods: {
    sort (sortKey) {
      console.log(`Sorting by ${sortKey}`)
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div><slot :rows="data"></slot></div>
  `
}
```

And your template becomes

```
<data-table :src="src">
  <template scope="{rows}">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <dt-th sort-key="name">Name</dt-th>
          <dt-th sort-key="surname">Surname</dt-th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="row in rows">
          <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.surname }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </template>
</data-table>
```

To solve your `dt-dh` issue you can expose it to Vue.

```
const DataTableHeaderCell = {
  props: ['sort-key'],
  methods: {
    emit () {
      EventBus.$emit('sort', this.sortKey)
    }
  },
  template: `
    <th @click="emit"><slot></slot></th>
  `
}

Vue.component("dt-th", DataTableHeaderCell)
```

Here is your [plunkr updated](https://plnkr.co/edit/9e9cg5AtsgGl7BVHntb5?p=preview).

Another alternative would be to pass the definition of the `DataTableHeaderCell` through the scope as well.

```
const DataTable = {
  props: ['src'],
  data () {
    return {
      data: [
        { name: 'Gale', surname: 'Marlon' },
        { name: 'Corwin', surname: 'Hayden' }
      ], 
      DataTableHeaderCell
    }
  },
  created () {
    EventBus.$on('sort', this.sort)
  },
  methods: {
    sort (sortKey) {
      console.log(`Sorting by ${sortKey}`)
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div><slot :rows="data" :header="DataTableHeaderCell"></slot></div>
  `
}
```

And in your template

```
<data-table :src="src">
  <template scope="{rows, header}">
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th :is="header" sort-key="name">Name</th>
          <th :is="header" sort-key="surname">Surname</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr v-for="row in rows">
          <td>{{ row.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ row.surname }}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </template>
</data-table>
```

Here is an [example](https://plnkr.co/edit/0DuNLlxKTUMq3NNlmTwx?p=preview) of that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've learned something new. I was planning to look into render functions in order to solve this problem. Still thinking that there could be a way of implementing it without the addition of `<template>` tag, but this would do more than enough for me.